# Filter DataFrame to delete duplicate values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following dataframe

```
date                |   value    | ID
--------------------------------------
2021-12-06 15:00:00      25        1
2021-12-06 15:15:00      35        1
2021-11-30 00:00:00      20        2
2021-11-25 00:00:00      10        2
```

I want to join this DF with another one like this:

```
idUser | Name | Gender
-------------------
1       John    M
2       Anne    F
```

My **expected** output is:

```
ID | Name | Gender | Value
---------------------------
1    John    M        35
2    Anne    F        20
```

What I need is: Get only the most recent value of the first dataframe and join only this value with my second dataframe. Although, my spark script is joining both values:

My code:

```
df = df1.select(
   col("date"),
   col("value"),
   col("ID"),
).OrderBy(
   col("ID").asc(),
   col("date").desc(),
).groupBy(
   col("ID"), col("date").cast(StringType()).substr(0,10).alias("date")
).agg (
   max(col("value")).alias("value")
)

final_df = df2.join(
    df,
    (col("idUser") == col("ID")),
    how="left"
)
```

When i perform this join (formating the columns is abstracted in this post) I have the following output:

```
ID | Name | Gender | Value
---------------------------
1    John    M        35
2    Anne    F        20
2    Anne    F        10
```

I use `substr` to remove hours and minutes to filter only by date. But when I have the same ID in different days my output df has the 2 values instead of the most recently. How can I fix this?

Note: I'm using only pyspark functions to do this (I now want to use `spark.sql(...)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window` and `row_number` function in pysaprk

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number

windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("date").desc()

df1_latest_val = df1.withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(windowSpec)).filter(
    f.col("row_number") == 1
)
```

The output of table `df1_latest_val` will look something like this

```
date                |   value    | ID | row_number |
-----------------------------------------------------
2021-12-06 15:15:00      35        1        1
2021-11-30 00:00:00      20        2        1
```

Now you will have df with the latest val, which you can directly join with another table.

Comment: What is the function of Window?

Comment: Window is used for apply operations on group of data. Like here, we are partitioning the data using `ID` so, rows with same `ID` will goto into one bucket/window, then we are soring the data inside the bucket, so in each bucket/window we have all the data of one ID in sorted order. Then we are adding row number column and filtering out the first row from each bucket/window.

Comment: I dont need to specify the dataframe i'm using window to partition?

Comment: First we created the windowSpec then we used that windowSpec in next line, so df info is passed to window function. You can write both in the same line too...